# Отмена удаления файла

Tags: git, git-push

Склонировал проект с помощью команды `git clone path`, после клонирования антивирус удалил один файл php. В результате если сделать `git status`, то показывает:
`deleted: file.php`.
Подскажите, как отменить это действие, т.е. чтобы можно было работать над проектом без этого файла?
т.е. чтобы при команте `git push` это действие по удалению файла не было запушено

Answer (score 5):

Сделайте восстановление файла. В большинстве случаев нужна команда `git checkout file.php`. Ну и антивирус удалите:) что бы не мешал.

p.s.

если файл просто не нужен, тогда

```
git add file.php
git commit "file.php was removed"
```

Comment: мне не нужно восстанавливать этот  файл. Мне нужно продолжить работу без этого файла, но чтобы при пуше уделение этого файла не было добавлено в индекс и в коммит

Comment: Вы хотите противоречивого. И удалять файл и не удалять.

Comment: где вы увидели, что я хочу его удалять? Мне нужно, чтобы удаление этого файла не попало в индекс и в коммит

Comment: файл был удален антивирусом. С одной стороны, Вы хотите продолжить без этого файла (тогда нужно закоммитить его удаление), с другой стороны, Вы хотите, что бы это удаление не было запушено (значит, это нужно восстановить)

Comment: а без восстановления файла можно будет пушить?
т.е. чтобы в новом коммите удаление не было видно?

Comment: собственно, если не делать git add для удаленного файла и пушить, то все должно отработать. "Удаление файла" на сервер не уйдет

Answer (score 5):

Я совершенно согласен с постом @KoVadim что можно всегда сделать `git checkout file` (если считать, что антивирус ошибся) или закоммитить удаление, если файл не нужен (антивирус не ошибся), однако я кажется понял потребность топикстартера (хоть и считаю её "странного хочет") и знаю хороший рецепт, что нужно делать в подобных случаях.

Во-первых, если очень хочется усидеть на двух стульях -- то нужно внести файл в список исключений, но не в `.gitignore`, а в `.git/info/exclude`. Этот файл у каждого клона репозитория свой и если хочется оттянуть принятие решения по этому файлу (закоммитить удаление или отменить удаление) -- то это самое удобное место.

Во-вторых, чтобы не забыть -- можно оставить как есть файл, просто будет не очень удобно коммитить, так как придётся аккуратно выбирать, что должно попасть в коммит, а что обойти. Мне например, из командной строки удобнее дать команду `git add .` или `git add -A`, чем выбирать файлы.

Так вот, можно просто добавлять в stage area сразу все файлы, но перед коммитом делать команду `git reset file`.

По-моему, эти два замечания прекрасно дополняют ответ @KoVadim, который -- ещё раз -- считаю наиболее правильным. Нечего держать в голове неразрешённый вопрос: надо решить и забыть.

Answer (score 4):

Можно добавить этот файл в `.gitignore` и продолжить без него. 
Другой вопрос, что это потребует коммита самого файла "исключений" в репозиторий, что не есть хорошо.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно пойти дальше и добавить сам `.gitignore` в `.gitignore`, тогда это решит проблему.

Как и другие отвечающие, считаю, что так в целом делать не стоит, и лучше просто добавить папку с проектами в исключения антивируса. Не стоит плодить костыли на ровном месте, когда все можно решить штатными средствами (или отключением онных вовсе).

Подробнее об игнорировании можно почитать вот [тут](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/215629)

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin На самом деле это именно является ответом (см. мой ответ), пусть и очень кратким и не полностью устраивающим топикстартера (нужно будет коммитить сам .gitignore). Автору ответа: пишите более подробные ответы! Иначе есть шанс того, что ваш ответ преобразуют в комментарий и вы не сможете получать за него баллы репутации.

Comment: Да, я не спорю это может быть ответом. Однако по правилам такие очень короткие сообщения расцениваются как комментарии и к сожалению могут быть преобразованы в комментарий или вовсе удалены.  Все-таки стоит писать более подробно, если не хотите иметь проблемы с проверкой.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, друзья. Я был в дороге и писал с телефона, думая что это комментарий, а не ответ, поэтому и так сформулировал. Это меня не оправдывает, но дело в невнимательности, а не умысле